# ByteArrayOutputStream capacity restriction

Tags: java, outputstream, capacity

I create `ByteArrayOutputStream barr = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1);`, i.e. with capacity 1 bytes and write to it more than 1 byte `barr.write("123456789000000".getBytes());`. No error occurs, I check the length of `barr` it is 15. Why my writing was not blocked or wrapped? Is there a way to prevent of writing more than capacity and which `outputstream` could be used for that?
I am very limited in available memory and don`t want to write there more than my limitations define

**P.S.** 
Thanks a lot for the answers! I had a following up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018984/writing-to-outputstream-having-capacity-restriction)
It could be great if you could look

Comment: According to the Javadoc, "The buffer automatically grows as data is written to it." [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Comment: I.e - the given capacity is an initial one?

Comment: Correct - the int param in the constructor is just the initial size of the array buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the capacity that you specify to the constructor is the **initial** size of the buffer. If you write more data, the buffer will be automatically re-allocated with a larger size, to fit more data.

As far as I know, there is no way with `ByteArrayOutputStream` to limit the growth of the buffer. You could use something else instead, for example a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, which has a fixed size.

Answer (score 4):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` will grow the backing array if you try to write more bytes.  This is usually thought of as a good thing.

If you want different behavior, you can always write your own `OutputStream` implementation that throws an IOException if the number of bytes to write goes beyond the capacity.

`ByteArrayOutputStream` is not final, so you can extend it.  I think all you would have to do is override `write(int)` and `write(byte[], int, int)` to throw Exception if the number of bytes to write is more than the amount remaining.  The fields `buf` and `count` are protected so your subclass should be able to see how much of the backing array is written to and the length of the array

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and eventually turned up an existing implementation of the same thing within Hadoop - [BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java](https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/io/file/tfile/BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java)