# writing to OutputStream having capacity restriction

Tags: java, outputstream, capacity

Following the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018341/bytearrayoutputstream-capacity-restriction) I asked before: I am implementing an `ByteArrayOutputStream` having capacity restriction. My main limitation is an amount of available memory. So having such stream `os`:

1. When I write more than say `1MB` to the output stream I need to "stop".
   I prefer not throw exception but write the complete contents of `os`
   output stream to the specified other output stream argument.

   `OutputStream out; 
   os.writeTo(out);`

   And after that continue the writings to `os` from its beginning
2. In order to prevent the situation described at 1. , I prefer to drain `os`,
   as freuqntely as possible. I mean copy the data from it to `out` in chuncks
   of 512KB 
   Is it feasible? If yes any advices how can it be done? Or may be there is a built in class which answers my requirements

**Edit:** The amount of bytes written to `out` is also limited. I can write there up to 1GB. If I have more, I need to create other output stream in order to drain from `os` there.
The proccess of writing to os. can be like that. 500MB was written there - I transfer it immidiately to out. After several seconds 700MB were written there - I need to drain only 500MB to `out` and other 200MB to other outputstream(`out2`), which I`ll need to create upon  such situation

Comment: You might find the default buffer size of 8 KB for a BufferedOutputStream perform just fine and increasing the buffer size can actually hurt performance as it's not as cache friendly.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey AFAIK, the optimal buffer sizes should be multiple of 4 Kb (the typical page size on most architectures), in order to read/write complete pages into disk. Why would a bigger size hurt performance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the actual requirement here? It sounds awfully like a really complicated way to reimplement `BufferedOutoutStream` to me.

Comment: @LittleSanti When you have larger buffers you are copying data between slower caches.  From testing I have for 32 KB to be fastest in some cases, though not much faster than 8 KB which is the default.  1 MB is usually slower for the cases I have tested.

Comment: @EJP Looking at the documentation is not clear how can I use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is a BufferedOutputStream, which you can construct like that :

```
new BufferedOutputStream(out, 512000)
```

The first arg is the other outputstream you have and the second one is the size of the BufferedOutputStream internal buffer

EDIT:

ok, i did not fully understand your need at first. You will indeed need to extend OutputStream to achieve that. Here is a sample code :

Here is how to use the below code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AtomicLong idx = new AtomicLong(0);
        try (
            OutputStream out = new OutputStreamMultiVolume(10, () -> new FileOutputStream(getNextFilename(idx)));
            ) {

            out.write("01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
    }

    private static File getNextFilename(AtomicLong idx) {
        return new File("sample.file." + idx.incrementAndGet() + ".txt");
    }
```

The first constructor arg of OutputStreamMultiVolume is the max size of a volume. If we reach this size, we will close the current outputStream, and call the OutputStreamSupplier to get the next one.

The example code here will write the String `01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789` (5 times 0123456789) to files named 'sample.file.idx.txt' where idx is increased each time we reach the outstream max size (so you'll get 5 files).

and the class intself :

```
public class OutputStreamMultiVolume extends OutputStream {

    private final long maxBytePerVolume;
    private long bytesInCurrentVolume = 0;
    private OutputStream out;
    private OutputStreamSupplier outputStreamSupplier;

    static interface OutputStreamSupplier {
        OutputStream get() throws IOException;
    }

    public OutputStreamMultiVolume(long maxBytePerOutput, OutputStreamSupplier outputStreamSupplier) throws IOException {
        this.outputStreamSupplier = outputStreamSupplier;
        this.maxBytePerVolume = maxBytePerOutput;
        this.out = outputStreamSupplier.get();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        final int remainingBytesInVol = (int) (maxBytePerVolume - bytesInCurrentVolume);
        if (remainingBytesInVol >= bytes.length) {
            out.write(bytes);
            bytesInCurrentVolume += bytes.length;
            return;
        }

        out.write(bytes, 0, remainingBytesInVol);
        switchOutput();

        this.write(bytes, remainingBytesInVol, bytes.length - remainingBytesInVol);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (bytesInCurrentVolume + 1 <= maxBytePerVolume) {
            out.write(b);
            bytesInCurrentVolume += 1;
            return;
        }

        switchOutput();
        out.write(b);
        bytesInCurrentVolume += 1;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        final int remainingBytesInVol = (int) (maxBytePerVolume - bytesInCurrentVolume);
        if (remainingBytesInVol >= len) {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            bytesInCurrentVolume += len;
            return;
        }

        out.write(b, off, remainingBytesInVol);
        switchOutput();
        this.write(b, off + remainingBytesInVol, len - remainingBytesInVol);
        bytesInCurrentVolume += len - remainingBytesInVol;
    }

    private void switchOutput() throws IOException {
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        out = outputStreamSupplier.get();
        bytesInCurrentVolume = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: the out is also limited. I can write to out up to 1G. and if I have more start to run to other output stream

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that your original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018341/bytearrayoutputstream-capacity-restriction) was not fully explained, and so were not the answers you got.

You should not use nor extend [BytArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) for flushing, because its main feature is to "write data into a byte array": i.e.: all the data is *in memory*, so you can retrieve it at later through `toByteArray`.

If you want to *flush* your exceding data, you need a *buffered* aproach: It is enough with this construction:

```
OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(...);
out=new BufferedOutputStream(out, 1024*1024);
```

In order to flush the data periodically, you can schedule a TimerTask to invoke `flush`:

```
Timer timer=new Timer(true);
TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask(){
   public void run()
   {
        try
        {
            out.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ...
        }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, delay, period);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure use of an OutputStream from multiple threads requires synchronization.

Comment: @VGR That's a good point to be careful of, but the answer is no: All the BufferedOutputStream's methods are already `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try using a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` in combination with a `java.nio.channel.Channels` that has a method `newChannel(OutputStream);`

Like so:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);
//... use buffer
OutputStream out = ...
drainBuffer(buffer, out);
```

and

```
public void drainBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer, OutputStream stream) {
   WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(stream);
   channel.write(buffer);
}
```